# Usage of select() function to identify binding template in HTML

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I have not been able to find any documentation for the `select()` function that I have seen used to identify binding templates in Windows 8 store apps, nor have I been able to find it defined in the WinJS `base.js` or `ui.js` files. It seems to work like a normal CSS selector to identify the `itemTemplate`:

```
<div id="listViewTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <h1 data-win-bind="textContent: firstName"></h1>
</div>

<div id="listViewDiv" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
    data-win-options="{itemTemplate: select('#listViewTemplate')}">   <==== HERE <====
</div>
```

When identifying a binding template by its `id`, the use of the `select()` function seems to be optional. However, if using its class name, `select()` seems to be required.

Where is the `select()` function documented or defined?

Comment: Make sure **not** to identify templates by their `id` if you are using a `PageControl`, as it will not work ([see reason here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13485062/1309005)). On `PageControls`, always use `select()` with the template's class name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in `base.js`, line 2712, and ultimately calls [querySelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288169%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (or [querySelectorAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304115%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

If you put a breakpoint at `_evaluateObjectQueryExpression` in `base.js` (around Line 6154) and step through, you'll get some insight as to how the value is parsed.

Comment: Digging into how WinJS implemented this functionality with the options format, it's kinda cool -- you can use it for your own attributes, and do lots of other magic.